# Is this a complete list of rules for importing packages and modules in Python?

Tags: python, module, package, ironpython

Currently I'm trying to collect a complete list of rules for importing Python modules and packages. As far as I know this should be a complete list, but I am not totally sure.

### Import rules for Python modules and packages:

**First scenario**

`import foo`

tries to find: `foo/__init__.py` if this exists: import / exit
tries to find: `foo.py` if this exists: import / exit

---

**Second scenario**

`import foo.bar`

tries to find: `foo/__init__.py`: if this exists: import
tries to find: `foo/bar/__init__.py`: if this exists: import / exit
tries to find: `foo/bar.py`: if this exists: import exit

---

**Third scenario**

`from foo import foo1`

same as `import foo`

---

**Fourth scenario**

`from foo.bar import foobar`

same as `import foo.bar`

---

It would be nice if someone could mention if I am missing something. In this case I would complete the list, for anyone else who wants to know this.

Comment: You forgot all the namespace stuff.

Comment: Do you mean with namespace stuff IronPython namespaces for .net?

Comment: Nope. [Namespaces.](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0420/)

Comment: List questions are **not** a good fit for SO's Q&A model.